# How can I get an application's password in Keychain?

Tags: icloud, keychain

The password is stored in my iCloud Keychain. I'm trying to **Show password** but when I enter my password nothing happens. There is a note "Access for this item cannot be edited" in the **Access Control** tab and only the app's access group is presented below, I can't edit this. How can I get this password?